# Turn off auto-hyperlinking in Notes app for macOS

Tags: macos, notes.app

A lot of my notes have links in them, but I don't want them to automatically be changed into hyperlinks after pressing space or enter.

I'd like them to remain as plain text without having to manually remove the link by right-clicking.

How can I turn this feature off? I'm guessing there might be a way to do this in terminal but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. Open your note.
2. Go to **Edit** then **Substitutions** and uncheck **Smart Links**

It will resolve your open query.

Also, uncheck Smart Copy/Paste to be more precise and if necessary.

Comment: Apple should have put this in Preferences...

Answer (score 1):

For an "at the end of the task" solution, you can Select All, Go to Format menu, font item and choose "Remove Style".  You can also bind a shortcut for the same in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts, under Application shortcuts tab.

[image]

Another slightly clumsy approach is to select the link and copy-paste it without style.

- [How to force OS X Notes application to lose formatting when I paste text from clipboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84823/how-to-force-os-x-notes-application-to-lose-formatting-when-i-paste-text-from-cl/84824#84824)